# Ошибка: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas, type-error

У меня есть такой датасет (это только кусок):

```
   Login   Password
0   Jack      12345
1  admin       2323
```

Также я написал функцию, которая получает на вход какую-то строку и печатает строку из таблицы, в которой в столбце `Login` лежит полученное значение (если оно там есть):

```
def check_password(login):
    check = info.iloc(info['Login'] == str(login))
    print(check)

file = 'users.csv'
info = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=';', names=['Login', 'Password'])
check_password('Jack')
```

Но что бы я не делал на строке:

```
check = info.iloc(info['Login'] == str(login))
```

получаю такую ошибку:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Полазив на англоязычной версии сайта, я нашел решение похожей проблемы. Там описывается, что флаг должен быть таким, чтобы Pandas мог высчитать его хеш. В ответе говорилось использовать `int` или `str` значения. Но я не понимаю, где я ошибся, если флаг у меня - `str` значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [164]: name = "Jack"

In [165]: df.query("Login == @name")["Password"]
Out[165]: 
0    12345
Name: Password, dtype: int64
```

чтобы получить результат как скалярное значение - берем пароль для **первой** совпавшей строки:

```
In [166]: df.query("Login == @name")["Password"].iat[0]
Out[166]: 12345
```

Comment: Все работает, большое спасибо.